# SQL Inner Join on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a SQL table of timestamps, station_code, temperature, humidity, pressure.
The timestamp and station_code are unique keys.
The data is gathered at regular 5 minute intervals.

I am trying to restructure the data into 3 tables, temperature, humidity, and pressure that would have unique timestamps for rows, and station_code for columns.

I am currently at a loss on how the join statement would go.

Any help would be appreciated.

With data from Excel,

[image]

Can easily produce a pivot table.

[image]

The end goal here is to pull out the specific sensor data for analysis.

Comment: assuming the timestamps are the same forall 3 table male an inner join woth on t1.stations_code = t2.station_code and t1.timestamps = t2.timestamp. Of course you cann give all tables a autoincrement id and use that in the on clause

Comment: Looks like you have one table and now want 3? What is the problem on create 3 tables and use `INSERT values ... SELECT FROM yourTable`

Comment: There are no sensors here

Comment: So what is the problem doing pivot to create that table?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the timestamps match exactly, you would just join on timestamp and station_code...

... but since MySQL does not have a true FULL outer join, that would mean you would either have to guarantee all 3 tables always have a match, or specific tables always had data in a certain order (so that a LEFT join could be used). Both of which suggest you probably should not decompose the original table.

It's unlikely to save you much space either as the redundant timestamp and station_code values are likely to take as much space as you would save by avoiding storing NULL measurements.

Comment: if my understanding is correct OP has 1 table and now want 3

Comment: Yes; my answer is that they can just join on timestamp and station code, with a big footnote that restructuring might not be a good idea for their data.